# DDRAM Rack and channels

Tags: memory, computer-architecture, ramdisk

I have a question regarding the DDRAM architecture: I was reading a scientific paper regarding a new processor that reduces power consumption while keeping a very high level of performances, and as example of power consumption the authors wrote

> With a practical memory channel
>   bandwidth of 10 GBps (DDR3-1600), to scan a nominal workload
>   size of 10 TB in under a second, we require 1000 channels per
>   rack.

My question is the following: what is a rack? and what are their channels? I tried to look up on wikipedia, but I only get a description of the racks used to connect various server in the same physical place. Since DDRAM is usually on the motherboard, I doubt the author was referring to this.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A channel is a single lane for data to travel to and from memory. Memory typically comes in single-, dual-, and quad-channel RAM modules, resulting in 1x, 2x, and 4x data units (e.g. 64-bit) moving per cycle. Imagine a channel being like a lane on a road for a car. The more lanes you have, the more data can move at once.

A rack refers to a server rack. It's a (typically) metal chassis that has "units" where "rack-mounted" devices can be attached. Racks are typically 12, 18, or 24  units high (though other sizes are certainly possible), and modules you can install in a rack have a size measured in U (units). So, in a 12U rack, you can install 6 2U units, or 12 1U units, or 3 2U units and another 6 1U units; any combination that adds up to the maximum size.

What they're talking about is using rack-mounted server RAM boards to install a number of RAM modules equal to 1000 channels, which may be 500 dual-channel modules or 250 quad-channel modules. In this design, the RAM modules would be attached via a super-high-speed backplane capable of transferring gigabytes or even terabytes of data per second, attached to several rack-mounted modules that hold all the DDR memory they're talking about.

A rack and a channel have absolutely nothing to do with each other. Channels are a feature of RAM and other types of buses. A rack is a physical chassis upon which modules or even entire servers are installed. For example, a rack might have a network module, a server module, a NAS module, and a power module. Other configurations are also possible depending on the resources needed by the server.

Comment: The original text may have meant physical RAM "slots" instead of "channels".  Processor which used DDR3 topped out at quad-channel, but modern Xeons and Epyc processors using DDR4 could be six- or eight-channel.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture .  By comparison, the most RAM slots I've seen in 1 unit is 24 slots.  24 slots times 40 units, the tallest rack I've seen, is 960.  I suspect the original author was overengineering (designing for more workload than would be normally expected, as a safety measure).

Comment: @ChristopherHostage BTW, original text appears to be http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~venkatv/MICRO-50_223-Camera-Ready.pdf, they're talking about a Data Processing Unit, a purpose-built rack for searching 10TB data/second. A cursory search for DD3 shows that DD3 2-channel runs at about 20000 MB/sec and 4-channel runs at about 40000 MB/sec, depending on clock speeds. I really do think they meant they were going to use at most 500 DDR3 modules, along with specialized hardware to improve bandwidth. What do you think?

Comment: Wasn't going to guess at the source text, but I have repeatedly seen people in the past say "channel" when they mean "slot".  For consumer PCs, the numbers are the same.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was very clear. The paper is not the one you mentioned, but the idea is the same, involving the usage of DPUs.